Ngspice or Spice models equations
I am trying to learn more about circuit simulation therefore I'm studying the ngspice source code.
To better understand how the devices are modelled for the different analysis (op, ac, tran) it would be usefull to have all the models equations ready to hand but I was not able to find them.
Can someone tell me if they exist and where I can find them?
Any book reference would be helpful as well.

Do you know how to set up a directed graph of a circuit? Just the bipolar transistor alone has many models: Ebers-Moll, Gummel-Poon, VBIC, and MEXTRAM. And many versions of each. Do you know what the initial transient solution step is and which run card it applies to and why? You seem far behind the curve. No one book will suffice. But at least read "SPICE2: A Computer Program to Simulate Semiconductor Circuits" by Laurence W. Nagel. If you haven't mastered that first, nothing else matters. So start there and then come back.

Yes, actually know every model you mentioned and I am even able to solve circuits by hand and even able to design them. My question is different though and your link doesn't provide any help at all! By the way, I got my electronics engineering degree more than 30 years ago and I'm using circuit simulators since then. Now I need to deeply look inside them. Here my two cents, if you don't know the answer you can remain silent!

I've no idea what you want, then. Nagel's dissertation really does cover all the topics you appear to be asking about. But perhaps graph theory, added? No clues. Anyway, best wishes. Obviously I can't read your writing with any understanding. So we part company.
